# Member of Container Class Can't be a Base Class

Tags: c++, base-class

I have a container class that does things with its member. This member should be a derived class, because there can be a few types of it. I would like to write the same code in this container class that works with this member no matter what type of derived class it is. However, I can't even get this to run. It compiles, but the runtime error is `/bin/sh: ./virtual_member_test: No such file or directory`. Here's some example code. Why doesn't this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:  
    Base();
    ~Base();
    virtual void foo(std::string s); // also tried making this pure virtual but doesn't compile
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    ~Derived1();
    void foo(std::string s) {std::cout << s << " 1" << std::endl;};
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2();
    ~Derived2();
    void foo(std::string s) {std::cout << s << " 2" << std::endl;};
};

class Container
{
public:
    Base m_thing;
    Container(Base thing);
    ~Container();
};

Container::Container(Base thing) : m_thing(thing)
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you leave the prototype like this:

```
virtual void foo(std::string s);
```

The method is not defined, thus the linker is not satisfied.

When you change the prototype to this:

```
virtual void foo(std::string s) = 0;
```

The method is a pure virtual one, and the compiler won't allow creation of `Base` instances, thus the compiler is angry.

Instead, if you want to use polymorphism, you should hold a **pointer** to `Base` rather than an instance:

```
class Container
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> m_thing;
    Container(std::shared_ptr<Base> thing) : m_thing(thing) {}
};
```

And create `Container` instances using:

```
Container container(std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(std::make_shared<Derived1>()));
```

Comment: ok, cool, look's like I've got some stuff to read up on. Thanks @DanielTrugman

Comment: @Taylor, have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to defined the base class virtual function

`virtual void foo(std::string s){}`

or if you want to make it a `pure virtual function` you cannot have instance of Base class so make it hold pointer of Base class by doing `Base* m_thing;`